# India to Glasgow via Dublin Etihad Airways

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, ireland, dub

I am travelling from India to Glasgow via Dublin on Etihad Airways. I am an Indian citizen and have a UK standard 6-months visa (which has not been used before).

The flight from Abu Dhabi to Dublin arrives at Terminal 1, and the connecting flight from Dublin to Glasgow (operated by Aer Lingus) departs from Terminal 2. Do I need an Irish visa for this transfer?

If you have taken a similar flight, please share your experience in transiting from T1 to T2 in the Dublin Airport.

Comment: @MichaelHampton edited the question with visa and citizen status. Indian passport, with 6-months UK visa (not used before).